# AMQP | RabbitMQ | Why do they have Fanout exchange when the same can be achieved via Direct Exchange bounded by multiple queues with same routing key?

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, amqp

Newbie to AMQP/RabbitMQ. Trying to grasp the concepts/principles and have stumbled upon this.

What is the difference between the following two paradigms?

**Fanout Exchange:**
FanoutExchange --> Queue1 (Routing Key 1), Queue2 (Routing Key 1),

vs

**Direct Exchange:**
DirectExchange --> Queue1 (Routing Key 1), Queue2 (Routing Key 1),

Doesn't both achieve the same effect? 
if not, please can someone throw light on how is it different and what is preferred over other in which cases?

Why do they have these two types of exchanges when both can be achieved by tweaking the routing key in the binding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the two paradigms you showed CAN achieve the same effect. But the idea behind these two kinds of exchange is totally different.

- **Fanout Exchange**. While using Fanout Exchange, all you need to do is to bind a queue to certain Fanout Exchange, despite the binding key you used when declaring the binding. [In fact, whatever binding key you use to declare a binding to a Fanout Exchange, RabbitMQ simply ignore it.](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html) Thus you can see a Fanout Exchange focuses more on fanouting message to whatever queues that bind to it.

  > The meaning of a binding key depends on the exchange type. The fanout exchanges, which we used previously, **simply ignored its value**.
- **Direct Exchange**. Direct exchange has a little more restriction when binding. The binding key MUST be exactly the same with the routing key which is attached to certain message. So a Direct Exchange is more flexible when sending different messages with diffrent ruoting key, and distributing these messages to different queues that bind to it using different 'binding key'.

  > Msg1,Msg2 (routingKey_1) --> DirectExchange_1 --> Queue1,
  >   Queue2 (bindingKey_1).
  >
  > 【bindingKey_1 = routingKey_1】
  >
  > Msg3(routingKey_2) --> DirectExchange_1 --> Queue3(bindingKey_2)
  >
  > 【bindingKey_2 = routingKey_2】